# Is there a name for aircraft weapon load photos?

Tags: military

I remember as a kid I had a couple of books full of spec sheets and big glossy photos of military planes with every standard piece of weaponry laid out in front of them, something like this (c/o Tech Sgt. Robert Horstman/US Air Force via [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/heres-how-many-bombs-a-b-52-can-haul-2015-6)):

[image]

Is there a standard (official or unofficial) name for this kind of staged photo?

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!

Comment: First idea: static display

Comment: Also: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12694/how-do-i-take-pictures-of-planes-flying-at-an-airshow

Comment: what about: vanity shot?